# Pandas: read_csv indicating 'space-delimited'

Tags: python, pandas, io

I have the following file.txt (abridged):

```
SICcode        Catcode        Category                              SICname        MultSIC
0111        A1500        Wheat, corn, soybeans and cash grain        Wheat        X
0112        A1600        Other commodities (incl rice, peanuts)      Rice        X
0115        A1500        Wheat, corn, soybeans and cash grain        Corn        X
0116        A1500        Wheat, corn, soybeans and cash grain        Soybeans        X
0119        A1500        Wheat, corn, soybeans and cash grain        Cash grains, NEC        X
0131        A1100        Cotton        Cotton        X
0132        A1300        Tobacco & Tobacco products                  Tobacco        X
```

I'm having some problems reading it into a pandas df. I tried `pd.read_csv`with the following specifications `engine='python', sep='Tab'`but it returned the file in one column:

```
    ﻿SICcode Catcode Category SICname MultSIC
0   0111 A1500 Wheat, corn, soybeans...
1   0112 A1600 Other commodities (in...
2   0115 A1500 Wheat, corn, soybeans...
3   0116 A1500 Wheat, corn, soybeans...
```

Then I tried to put it into a gnumeric file using 'tab' as a delimiter, but it read the file as one column. Does anyone have an idea on this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If `df = pd.read_csv('file.txt', sep='\t')` returns a DataFrame with one column, then apparently `file.txt` is not using tabs as separators. Your data *might* simply have spaces as separators. In that case you could try

```
df = pd.read_csv('data', sep=r'\s{2,}')
```

which uses the regex pattern `\s{2,}` as the separator. This regex matches 2-or-more whitespace characters.

```
In [8]: df
Out[8]: 
   SICcode Catcode                                Category           SICname  \
0      111   A1500    Wheat, corn, soybeans and cash grain             Wheat   
1      112   A1600  Other commodities (incl rice, peanuts)              Rice   
2      115   A1500    Wheat, corn, soybeans and cash grain              Corn   
3      116   A1500    Wheat, corn, soybeans and cash grain          Soybeans   
4      119   A1500    Wheat, corn, soybeans and cash grain  Cash grains, NEC   
5      131   A1100                                  Cotton            Cotton   
6      132   A1300              Tobacco & Tobacco products           Tobacco   

  MultSIC  
0       X  
1       X  
2       X  
3       X  
4       X  
5       X  
6       X
```

If this does not work, please post `print(repr(open(file.txt, 'rb').read(100))`. This will show us an unambiguous representation of the first 100 bytes of `file.txt`.

Answer (score 2):

I think you can try add `sep="\t"` to [`read_csv`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html) if data in `csv` are separated by `Tabulator`.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('test/a.csv', sep="\t")
print df
   SICcode Catcode                               Category           SICname  \
0      111   A1500   Wheat, corn, soybeans and cash grain             Wheat   
1      112   A1600  ther commodities (incl rice, peanuts)              Rice   
2      115   A1500   Wheat, corn, soybeans and cash grain              Corn   
3      116   A1500   Wheat, corn, soybeans and cash grain          Soybeans   
4      119   A1500   Wheat, corn, soybeans and cash grain  Cash grains, NEC   
5      131   A1100                                 Cotton            Cotton   
6      132   A1300             Tobacco & Tobacco products           Tobacco   

  MultSIC  
0       X  
1       X  
2       X  
3       X  
4       X  
5       X  
6       X
```

Comment: I tried your suggestion and it returns the df in one column. I'll try changing the extension to `csv`from `txt`.

Comment: Ok, I think you can try open file in some editor, e.g. notepad ++ and check separator of columns. Is it tab? Or only whitespaces?

Comment: It is tab at 8 spaces.